# "Harmonic oscillator" with $p$-Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I wonder if there is any literature on the eigenvalue problem for the  "$p$-harmonic oscillator" $$-(|u'|^{p-2}u')'(x)+(x^2-\lambda) |u(x)|^{p-2} u(x)=0$$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$, $p\in(1,\infty)$. Are there any explicit expressions for the eigenvalues and/or the eigenfunctions?